# postgres store with composite value type, or a better way of attributing an inverted index

Tags: postgresql, hstore, inverted-index

can't seem to figure out the syntax for populating a hstore with a **value** of composite type -- note: I do not want to convert a record to a hstore.

```
select hstore('hello => ROW(1,2)');
```

I know it's something simple; However, google is not my friend today.

use case : custom inverted index.

The data is modelling an inverted index of lexemes, the composite data types are various probabilities related to the lexemes which I will use to implement document clustering. Does anyone know a better way of doing this ? I'm open to using an external system if it allows attaching attributes to key->posting pairs in the inverted index.

I'd use something external if it had solid support for what I am trying to do, I suspect that sticking 3-10k lexemes per tuple and then doing batch processing on them is gonna be nasty as the whole hstore will have to be parsed and converted.

At the moment my lexemes are in the range of 50-1k per tuple, mostly in the low hundreds, and i'm just doing it for my research algorithms. But there has to be a better way of doing this.

Comment: "inverted index of lexemes". Sounds like you might actually be looking for `tsearch2` (full text search), `GIN` and or `GiST` indexes.

Comment: I already have a `gin(ts_vector)` index as a basic interface to the data :D I am doing research in IR so I need to implement additional metrics.  I've actually looked into implementing a custom `gin` or `gist` index with a sparse vector data type backing it but that might be an overkill approach for the time being.

Comment: Good to hear. Unfortunately I suspect any approach using complex hstore values will be incredibly underwhelming in performance terms. You'll probably get better results with simple table based key/value attribute storage or a table with an array in it.

Comment: Yeah :(, good thing I don't need performance at the moment. I will however send an email to the chaps maintaining the gin/gist codebase and see if I could work on something with them. Thanks for the help :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings in `hstore` are double-quoted. `hstore` only supports text values, nothing else, so you must store other types as their text representations:

```
SELECT hstore('k => "(1,2)"');
```

eg:

```
regress=> SELECT (hstore('k => "(1,2)"')) -> 'k';
 ?column? 
----------
 (1,2)
(1 row)
```

This means you have to cast the values to use them, eg:

```
regress=> CREATE TYPE pair AS (a integer, b integer);
CREATE TYPE
regress=> SELECT ((hstore('k => "(1,2)"')) -> 'k')::pair;
 pair  
-------
 (1,2)
(1 row)
```

or using arrays instead to avoid the composite type:

```
regress=> SELECT ((hstore('k => "{1,2}"')) -> 'k')::integer[];
 int4  
-------
 {1,2}
(1 row)
```

Arrays are indexed from 1 with the `[]` operator, eg `[1]`.

This is generally horrendously inefficient because the values must be parsed and converted every single time. It's not really practical to suggest alternatives when you haven't said much about the nature of your problem and why you want hstore in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for expanding, I knew it would go in as a string. That relates to the second part of my question.  it's gonna be terribly inefficient for implementing similarity metrics.

Comment: The `ROW` and `ARRAY` constructors are only valid when parsed as SQL. You'll need to use the string-literal form of your array or record.